# Why am I getting a FATAL_ERROR when I try to debug a program?

Tags: java, eclipse

I tried to debug a simple java program in Eclipse and I got this error:

> FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
>   ERROR: transport error 202: connect failed: Connection timed out
>   ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
>   JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [debugInit.c:750]

and I tried following setting vm in `eclipse.ini` file but it didn't work

Here is my `eclipse.ini`:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.300.v20150602-1417
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
```

Comment: What's your eclipse.ini file look like?

Comment: Please [edit] your question with that information so it's readable.

Comment: @durron597: I usually do too. And then when I forget... bam.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the `-vm` at the beginning of the `eclipse.ini` file, and it has to be on two separate lines. I don't think it matters, but on my machine it uses forward slashes even though it's Windows. Change it to this:

```
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_45/bin/javaw.exe
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.300.v20150602-1417
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
```

Also, please verify that it actually is in that location on your computer and not somewhere else.

Comment: @RameshRaj If I've helped you, don't forget to click the hollow checkmark next to the voting buttons at the top left of this post. See: [What should I do when someone's answered my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)